# Flutter programing svg design

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I designed a simple `svg` into this [website](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) and i'll to try programing that in flutter

[image]

I have implemented the code using this approach:

```dart
class AppbarBackgroundPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  AppbarBackgroundPainter(this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    /*Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(1, 50)
      ..moveTo(0, 33)
      ..lineTo(0, 41)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 40, 1, 40)
      ..lineTo(24, 40)
      ..cubicTo(27, 40, 27, 40, 29, 36)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(30, 34, 32, 34)
      ..lineTo(54, 34)
      ..lineTo(54, 33)
      ..lineTo(0, 33);*/

    /* converted SVG to dart*/
    Path path_0 = Path();

    path_0.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        0,
        size.height * 0.9207522,
        size.width * 0.006172833,
        size.height * 0.8837156,
        size.width * 0.01851852,
        size.height * 0.8837156);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.4444444, size.height * 0.8837156);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.5000000,
        size.height * 0.8837156,
        size.width * 0.5000000,
        size.height * 0.8837156,
        size.width * 0.5370370,
        size.height * 0.4392711);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.5493833,
        size.height * 0.2911222,
        size.width * 0.5679019,
        size.height * 0.2170489,
        size.width * 0.5925926,
        size.height * 0.2170489);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.2170489);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(0, 0);
    path_0.close();

    Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_0_fill.color = color;
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0_fill);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, I was unable to apply the things shown in the picture to the code. it should be used on `appbar` background

Comment: You can try to extend the custom class with ShapeBorder and use it in the Appbar(shape: AppbarBackgroundBorder())

Comment: so the question is how to use relative size?

Comment: @kherel could you help on this topic please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom `Border` to `AppBar` by overriding `ContinuousRectangleBorder` and setting it as `shape` property of `AppBar`

you can create custom border like this:

```dart
class CustomAppBarShape extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    double height = rect.height; // you can add different height here
    double width = rect.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, height + width * 0.02);
    path.arcToPoint(
      Offset(width * 0.02, height),
      radius: Radius.circular(width * 0.02),
    );
    path.lineTo(width * 0.6, height);
    path.cubicTo(
      width * 0.66,
      height,
      width * 0.64,
      height * 0.2,
      width * 0.7,
      height * 0.2,
    );

    path.lineTo(width, height * 0.2);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

Then you can pass it to `shape` of `AppBar` like this

```
AppBar(
  title: Text(widget.title),
  shape: CustomAppBarShape(),
)
```

the result will be something like this,

[image: result]

I have added approximate `path` based on image you provided, you can edit the `path` so that it is similar to the `path` in the code you provided, but instead of `CustomPainter` you can set custom border by setting the `shape` value of `AppBar`.

you can see live example [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=110a97572c138f543dbacca3e6be3198).

Edit:

To customize the left side width you can pass the width percentage or fraction as an argument to `CustomAppBarShape` constructor.

```dart
class CustomAppBarShape extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  
  final double leftWidthVal;
  
  const CustomAppBarShape({this.leftWidthVal = 0.5});
  
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    double height = rect.height; // you can add different height here
    double width = rect.width;
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, height + width * 0.02);
    path.arcToPoint(
      Offset(width * 0.02, height),
      radius: Radius.circular(width * 0.02),
    );
    path.lineTo(width * leftWidthVal, height);
    path.cubicTo(
      width * (leftWidthVal + 0.06),
      height,
      width * (leftWidthVal + 0.04),
      height * 0.2,
      width * (leftWidthVal + 0.1),
      height * 0.2,
    );

    path.lineTo(width, height * 0.2);
    path.lineTo(width, 0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }
}
```

and set the `leftWidthVal` value,

```dart
AppBar(
  title: Text(widget.title),
  shape: const CustomAppBarShape(leftWidthVal: 0.1),
)
```

if you set the value 0.1 or 10% result will be like this,

[image]

I have also updates the live example on dartpad.

Comment: thanks so much, how can i make responsive left side? such as 10% or 50%

Comment: Thanks :) how can i change white space of `appbar` which that's under the shape?

Comment: I think you can use `extendBodyBehindAppBar: true` in `Scaffold` widget to use the whitespace in the appbar

Comment: i apologize, my meant was white color of under the shape in appbar. i can't change that

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch `path_0` and simply rescale `path`:

```dart
Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = color;

final scalingfactor_w = size.width/50; //original svg size seemed to be 50
final scalingfactor_h = size.height/50; //original svg size seemed to be 50

var scalingMatrix =
        Float64List.fromList([scalingfactor_w, 0, 0, 0, 0, scalingfactor_h, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]);

path = path.transform(scalingMatrix);

canvas.drawPath(path, paint_0_fill);
```

this isnt a perfect fit if the appbar should start at the top but it should hint you in the right direction without needing to recode the whole path
(the transform matrix should also allow translation)

otherwise you might simply skip this and use [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)